# How to deploy a Jquery mobile project with phone gap

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile, deployment

i have created my Mobile application with Jquery mobile now i want it to deploy

now how should i deploy across platforms like and android Iphone etc.,

Phone Gap looks promising but it is confusing plus it looks like i have to re code stuff again

please Help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

jQuery mobile framework provides tools for mobile UI. It is used in combination with standard web application backends. Such applications are deployed on web servers! If you want to make hybride apps you can use PhoneGap, that's right.

PhoneGap projects use an open packaging model that follows the [W3C Widget Packaging specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/widgets/). You have to adjust your project according to the specifications or simply deploy it as a web application on a web server.